# OpenCL : Using vload Vs vector pointer

Tags: opencl

Is there any advantage of using vload Vs directly assigning vector pointer? Which would be faster in mobile GPU's with less computational power & bandwidth?

Ex:
**vload sample**

```
__kernel vec_add(__global const float* a, __global const float* b, __global float* c){
    float4 a_sub;
    float4 b_sub;
    float4 c_sub;

    a_sub = vload4(0, &a[get_global_id(0)]);
    b_sub = vload4(0, &b[get_global_id(0)]);

    c_sub = a_sub + b_sub;
   
    vstore(c_sub, 0, &c[get_global_id(0)]);
}
```

**vector pointer sample**

```
__kernel vec_add(__global const float* a, __global const float* b, __global float* c){
    float4 a_sub;
    float4 b_sub;
    float4 c_sub;

    a_sub = ((global const float4*)a)[get_global_id(0)];
    b_sub = ((global const float4*)b)[get_global_id(0)];;

    c_sub = a_sub + b_sub;
   
    vstore(c_sub, 0, &c[get_global_id(0)]);
}
```

Comment: What do you consider a "Mobile GPU"? Each hardware vendor have different implementations of vload/vstore and pointer access, so it really depends on how the OpenCL model is mapped onto the hardware.

Comment: Implementations change. You should benchmark overall performance or test both of them and pick faster one before production.

Comment: According to this old Intel video (https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/optimizing-simple-opencl-kernels-modulate-kernel-optimization) (jump to 3:25), vload can save a quite noticeable amount of time. The video is old though (2014), so perhaps no longer relevant

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments it depends on the target hardware which is the fastest way to load the data. In other words, you should benchmark which is the best or are there any difference. However, I can't remember achieving any speed up by changing the syntax.

If you need to work with `float*` buffers then the third option to try is to write the same load like this:

```
    a_sub = (float4){
        a[get_global_id(0) * 4 + 0],
        a[get_global_id(0) * 4 + 1],
        a[get_global_id(0) * 4 + 2],
        a[get_global_id(0) * 4 + 3]
    };
```

However, many times there is no reason to work with `float*` buffers and you could use `float4*` buffers. In that case the compiler can definitely know that the load is going to be aligned. Moreover, I have seen significant speed ups on mobile platforms when I changed the buffer type. So in your case the kernel signature would look like:

```
__kernel vec_add(__global const float4* a, __global const float4* b, __global float4* c){
```

and the load would be:

```
   a_sub = a[get_global_id(0)];
```

Comment: I get   """ IOCTL_KGSL_DEVICE_WAITTIMESTAMP_CTXTID) failed: errno 35 Resource deadlock avoided """ error when using const float4*

Comment: Solved the error. But I dont see any improvement between using vload4 with float* buffer & directly assigning a_sub = a[0] using float4* buffer. Both kernels take the same time in Adreno 830 GPU

Comment: Ok. If I remember correctly I got speed up by using `float4*`on couple of years old Mali platforms. If you need to make your loads faster you could try to use half-precision as a storage type.

Answer (score 0):

The `vloadn` and `vstoren` require alignment while "traditional C syntax" does not. So there is certainly opportunity for significant optimization in the former. Of course it will be up to your specific implementation so profiling is needed.